# "if parent category is" conditional?

Tags: php, conditional-tags

I searched through the codex but couldn't find anything helpful. I tried the code below but it didn't work. The default sidebar still shows up for all category pages.

```
    <?php
        $ep_category = get_the_category();

        if ($ep_category->category_parent == 'watch-isatv') { 
            include ('sidebar-isatv.php');
        }
        else {
            get_sidebar(); 
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution won't work, because `$ep_category->category_parent` is ID (integer) and not slug (string). So this comparison doesn't make any sense... ;)

One way to do this would be this function ([from Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category)):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
    function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
        foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
            // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
            if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

After adding it to your theme, you can use it this way:

```
if ( in_category( 'watch-isatv' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 11 ) ) ...  // where 11 is 'watch-isatv' category ID
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second part. Why are you using 'watch-isatv' twice? `watch-isatv` and `11`.

Comment: First part checks if given post is in this category and second part check if that post is in any of its children (subcategories).

Comment: I added the first part to my functions page and I added this in my archive template but the default sidebar still shows up: `<?php if ( post_is_in_descendant_category( 'watch-isatv' ) ) { include ('sidebar-isatv.php'); } else { get_sidebar(); } ?>` Did I mess up the code somehow?

Comment: Oh it works when I input the category ID. I wonder why it doesn't work with the slug. Anyway, thank you!